# Image capture within a label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userForm that consists of some buttons that have images on them.  I then have three blank labels that I would like when I click on a button / image the image shows up in the first label.  Then if I click on another button / image the second label is the image and the same for the third.

36 buttons labeled btn1 thru btn36
Three blank labels named capture1 capture2 capture3

I'm not sure if I need to post any other information or not.

I need help writing the code for this (VBA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basics of getting the image from the button to label are straightforward:

```
Capture1.Picture = btn1.picture
```

The real headache comes from the fact that you can't assign the same chunk of code to multiple Button.Click events in VBA.  Not like in VB where the syntax would be:

```
Sub MyRoutine(sender, <args>) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click...
```

In VBA you basically need 36 different _Click routines, 1 for each button.  Set up a module level counter to keep track of what label you want to reference.

```
Dim counter As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    counter = 1
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click()
   If counter > 3 Then
      counter = 1
    End If
    Controls("capture" & counter).Picture = btn1.Picture
    counter = counter + 1
End Sub
```

You'll need 36 routines that are identical to this except for the name of the button in each routine.  Fortunately, you can do it mostly with cut and paste.

You can save a few lines of code if you do it this way:

```
Private Sub btn1_Click()
   Call CaptureImage(btn1.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click()
   Call CaptureImage(btn2.Name)
End Sub
.
.
.
Private Sub CaptureImage(ByVal btnName As String)
    If counter > 3 Then
      counter = 1
    End If
    Controls("capture" & counter).Picture = Controls(btnName).Picture
    counter = counter + 1
End Sub
```

but you will still end up with 36 _Click routines that call the CaptureImage subroutine.